# Applying functions to a pandas DataFrame gives Value Error (just one argument)

Tags: python, pandas

It seems I can apply some functions without problems to a DataFrame, but other give a Value Error.

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=6)
data = np.random.randn(6,4)

df = pd.DataFrame(data,index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))

def my_max(y):
    return max(y,0)

def times_ten(y):
    return 10*y

df.apply(lambda x:times_ten(x)) # Works fine
df.apply(lambda x:my_max(x)) # Doesn't work
```

The first apply works fine, the second one generates a:

ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', u'occurred at index A')

I know I can generate the "max(df,0)" in other ways (e.g. by df[df<0]=0), so I'm not looking for a solution to this particular problem. Rather, I'm interested in why the apply above doesn't work.

Comment: from the docs: `With a single iterable argument, return its largest item.
With two or more arguments, return the largest argument.` so it doesn't understand pandas Series or numpy arrays in this context which is why you should use something that does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`max` cannot handle a scalar and an array:

```
>>> max(df['A'], 0)
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

either use [`np.maximum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) which does element-wise maximum:

```
>>> def my_max(y):
...     return np.maximum(y, 0)
... 
>>> df.apply(lambda x:my_max(x))
                A      B      C      D
2013-01-01  0.000  0.000  0.178  0.992
2013-01-02  0.000  1.060  0.000  0.000
2013-01-03  0.528  2.408  2.679  0.000
2013-01-04  0.564  0.573  0.320  1.220
2013-01-05  0.903  0.497  0.000  0.032
2013-01-06  0.505  0.000  0.000  0.000
```

or use [`.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap) which operates elementwise:

```
>>> def my_max(y):
...     return max(y,0)
... 
>>> df.applymap(lambda x:my_max(x))
                A      B      C      D
2013-01-01  0.000  0.000  0.178  0.992
2013-01-02  0.000  1.060  0.000  0.000
2013-01-03  0.528  2.408  2.679  0.000
2013-01-04  0.564  0.573  0.320  1.220
2013-01-05  0.903  0.497  0.000  0.032
2013-01-06  0.505  0.000  0.000  0.000
```

Comment: Ah, so the argument to my function is an array, and the magical thing isn't that max doesn't work (of course it doesn't) but that '10*y' actually do work.